# Online Customers with 0.0.0.0 IP address?

Tags: magento-1.8

We are seeing "online customers" in Magento with a 0.0.0.0 IP address !?

I know that isn't a valid IP address, so I'm curious what that indicates?

Comment: Oh, could this be due to a IPv6 connection?

Comment: If you're problem with IPv6 on online customers... Here is a manual to change you're settings in Magento core:
http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.de/2010/02/ipv6-for-online-customers.html I tried, but it dosn't work with Magento 1.9.1.0 Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

I might be off here, but if you have some sort of proxying going on then this *might* be the cause. If so it can be probably by fixed via Magento configuration:

```
<global>
    <remote_addr_headers>
        <header1>[some $_SERVER index with proper IP info]</header1>
    </remote_addr_headers>
</global>
```

Which value(s) you specify (index values from the `$_SERVER` superglobal) will depend on your configuration.

Comment: I think you are correct, I'm using Cloudflare and that may be part of what I'm seeing.  I do see orders with an IPv6 recorded with the order, and I'm now wondering if CloudFlare is proxying and connecting to my server via IPv6 and I'm losing the original IP address.  Gonna have to look into this.